Kafka Connect connector won't link up to a topic
In my work project I have some ksqlDB queries that rely on data provided by a topic that's supposed to be populated by a connector. Said connector isn't created through the ksqlDB CLI, but through the Kafka Connector CLI by employing a .sh file. I can tell that the Connector is properly created by looking at the Connector List in Kafka UI, however said connector doesn't seem to always link up to the expected topic.
Here's the content of my .sh file:
    `curl -X POST \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    --data '{
      "name": "source-sql-server",
      "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:sqlserver://x.x.x.x:x;databaseName=x;user=x;password=x",
        "mode": "incrementing",
        "incrementing.column.name": "column",
        "table.whitelist": "connector1",
        "topic.prefix": "topic_",
        "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
        "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
        "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
        "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081"
      }
    }' \`
http://localhost:8083/connectors

Does anybody know why this happens? Also this issue seems to be very inconsistent as sometimes (rarely)the topic gets actually created, however the data in the ksqlDB queries doesn't seem to update correctly anyway. Kafka UI
I've tried creating the topic through the .sh file and directly through the Kafka UI.
